# Replace default authentication strategy in Padrino-Warden

Tags: ruby, padrino, warden

Im struggling to replace the default :password strategy for the Padrino-Warden gem. 
The way I figure it I need to get a hold of the manager instance for warden so I can set the default strategies but I'm not sure how to do that in the app.rb file

Right now app.rb looks like this

```
register Padrino::Warden

Warden::Strategies.add(:udid) do
    def valid?
      puts "udid strat"
      params[:udid]
    end

    def authenticate!
      user = User.get(:udid => params[:udid])
      user.nil? ? fail!("Could not log in") : success!(user)
    end
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session do |user|
  user.id
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
  User.get(id)
end

use ::Warden::Manager do |manager|
     manager.scope_defaults :default, 
      strategies: [:password], 
      action: 'sessions/unauthenticated'
end
```

Which does not work. The warden environment still looks like this

```
Warden::Proxy:70352196940440 @config={:default_scope=>:default, :scope_defaults=>{}, :default_strategies=>{:_all=>[:password]}, :intercept_401=>true, :failure_app=>Dagis}
```

If I configure warden in config.ru it will set the correct environment for warden but then I suspect the session middleware provided by Padrino does not work well together with Warden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instruct the warden manager when to use the strategy. Update the `strategies` key that you're passing to the `use` method to reflect which strategies you want to enable and the order in which they should be run. You could do this:

```
use ::Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.scope_defaults :default, 
    strategies: [:udid, :password], 
    action: 'sessions/unauthenticated'
end
```

There's a bunch of examples on the [Warden wiki on github](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Setup)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end the problem seemed to be with padrino-warden which had too much assumptions about the configuration. Removed it and using only Warden works like a charm.